# Android application for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

As i new in android development i just want to know is there any way to develop Android application for different screen sizes ?

help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Most all the answers give you the initial background theory to build a flexible layout, but please also have a look at this official training: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your project.

res/values/main.xml

res/values-sw600dp/main.xml -> 7+ inches

res/values-sw720dp/main.xml -> 10+ inches
Create this folder and just copy your xml file in all the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Put your main.xml in those folders:

```
 res/values/   //your default values (in your case for phones)

 res/values-large/    //specfic values for relatively big screens

 res/values-xlarge/    //specific values for really big screens
```

> large: Screens that are of similar size to a medium-density VGA
>   screen. The minimum layout size for a large screen is approximately
>   480x640 dp units. Examples are VGA and WVGA medium density screens.
>
> xlarge: Screens that are considerably larger than the traditional
>   medium-density HVGA screen. The minimum layout size for an xlarge
>   screen is approximately 720x960 dp units. In most cases, devices with
>   extra large screens would be too large to carry in a pocket and would
>   most likely be tablet-style devices. Added in API level 9.

see more infos here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes

Answer (score 1):

Google provide good article how to support multiple screens

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

General advices:

use layout - for for mobile phone layouts
use layout-sw600dp folder for 7inch tablets layouts
use layout-sw720dp folder for 10inch tablets layouts

use dimens.xml in values folder to define dimentions for your UI
you also can use 
values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp with its own dimens.xml file for 7 and 10 inch tablets

Answer (score 0):

Writing apps for multiple devices requires one to have good knowledge on basic concepts like : what is Dpi, Screen density , Orientation etc.

Article below is good place to start for:

Supporting Multiple Screens
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html